# ASP.NET JWT bearer authentication not changing user in request context

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, oauth, jwt

I'm creating a simple OAuth server for my SPA, following along with [this](http://www.developerhandbook.com/c-sharp/create-restful-api-authentication-using-web-api-jwt/) tutorial. I can request a JWT fine from the OAuth provider. However, when I send the JWT along in the authorization header (like this: `Authorization Bearer <token>`) I always get a 401 "Authorization has been denied for this request".

Stepping through the code, I can see that my user in the request context is set to an anonymous Windows authentication user instead of the owner of the JWT.

I see a lot of people saying to put the `app.UseWebAPI()` call after the OAuth configuration, but I'm not registering the WebAPI in my startup.cs. Should I be? I currently don't have an `app.UseWebAPI()` anywhere in my code (and the API works fine without the authorization).

Here's my startup.cs:

```
public partial class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            ConfigureOAuth(app);
        }
    }

public partial class Startup
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// OAuth configuration
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="app"></param>
        public void ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // Unique identifier for the entity issuing the token
            var issuer = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["issuer"];
            // Private key used to secure the token
            var secret = TextEncodings.Base64Url.Decode(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["secret"]);

            // Enable JWT authentication
            app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
                AllowedAudiences = new[] { "Any" },
                IssuerSecurityTokenProviders = new IIssuerSecurityTokenProvider[]
                {
                    new SymmetricKeyIssuerSecurityTokenProvider(issuer, secret)
                }
            });

            // Create authentication endponit
            app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
            {
                AllowInsecureHttp = true,
                TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/login/"),
                AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(1),
                Provider = new CustomOAuthProvider(),
                AccessTokenFormat = new CustomJwtFormat(issuer)
            });
        }
    }
```

Here's my CustomOAuthProvider class:

```
public class CustomOAuthProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
    {
        IMessengerRepository repo;

        public CustomOAuthProvider() : base()
        {
            repo = new MessengerRepository();
        }

        public override Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
        {
            // Enable CORS
            context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { "*" });

            // Check against the repository to see if the login details are correct
            var user = repo.Authenticate(context.UserName, context.Password);

            // If the login details are incorrect, return an error
            if (user == null)
            {
                context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The username or password is incorrect");
                context.Rejected();
                return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
            }

            // Otherwise, return a JWT
            var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(SetClaimsIdentity(context, user), new AuthenticationProperties());
            context.Validated(ticket);

            return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
        }

        public override Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
        {
            // Because the audience is not validated, the request is validated straight away without any checks
            context.Validated();
            return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Create a ClaimsIdentity based on their username and role
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="context"></param>
        /// <param name="user"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static ClaimsIdentity SetClaimsIdentity(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context, UserDto user)
        {
            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity("JWT");

            // Add claims for the user themselves
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, context.UserName));
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim("sub", context.UserName));
            // Add claim for the user's role
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, user.UserRole.RoleName.TrimEnd(' ')));

            return identity;
        }
    }
```

and my CustomJwtFormat class:

```
public class CustomJwtFormat : ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket>
    {
        // Private key for encoding token
        private static readonly byte[] secret = TextEncodings.Base64Url.Decode(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["secret"]);
        // Entity issuing the token
        private readonly string issuer;

        public CustomJwtFormat(string issuer)
        {
            this.issuer = issuer;
        }

        public string Protect(AuthenticationTicket data)
        {
            if (data == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(data));

            var signingKey = new HmacSigningCredentials(secret);
            var issued = data.Properties.IssuedUtc;
            var expires = data.Properties.ExpiresUtc;

            return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(new JwtSecurityToken(issuer, null, data.Identity.Claims, issued.Value.UtcDateTime, expires.Value.UtcDateTime, signingKey));
        }

        public AuthenticationTicket Unprotect(string protectedText)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isaac,

Your implementation looks good, but there is a tiny problem with the `audience id`.

In your `CustomJwtFormat` for `authorization` you specify `null` as an audience id. While for `authentication` you specify `Any`.
This is the reason why you get a `401 Unauthorized`.

If you change your JwtSecurityToken with the following it will work.

```
return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(new JwtSecurityToken(issuer, "Any", data.Identity.Claims, issued.Value.UtcDateTime, expires.Value.UtcDateTime, signingKey));
```

Answer (score 0):

For new readers UseJwtBearerAuthentication() is obsolete.
https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.jwtbearerappbuilderextensions.usejwtbearerauthentication?view=aspnetcore-2.2